# Reading NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I read an Array that contains objects in this format:

```
Second pair: {
latitude = "26.499023";
longitude = "42.326061";
}
```

??

EDIT:

```
NO..this is the way I come up with that...   

NSArray *MaparrayLongitude = [dataMap objectForKey:@"longitude"];
NSArray *MaparrayLatitude = [dataMap objectForKey:@"latitude"];

if (MaparrayLongitude.count != MaparrayLatitude.count) {
    //Error: Unequal number of longitude/latitude values
} else {
    NSMutableArray *pairs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < MaparrayLongitude.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *pair = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [MaparrayLongitude objectAtIndex:i], @"longitude",
                              [MaparrayLatitude objectAtIndex:i], @"latitude", nil];
        [pairs addObject:pair];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer that I suspect you are looking for is called NSDictionary. 
I came from PHP where we called it an array if it was either numerically indexed or keyed with strings; in Objective-C, there are 3 basic kinds of collections:

NSArray - ordered, natural integers as indexes

NSSet - unordered collection, single-membership

NSDictionary - keyed on one of several kinds of objects, usually strings.

[Here is apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Edit: for reference, here is what your code might end up looking like:

```
double myLat = [[secondPair objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
```

EDIT (after your edit):
Perhaps it's fast enumeration, in conjunction with dictionary access that you seek:

```
for (NSDictionary *coordinate in pairs) {
  // lat = [coordinate objectForKey@"latitude"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a simply data structure with two float values, so I prefer

```
[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(26.499023, 42.326061)];
```

and store it into the array. And for getting the value, you can do like:

```
CGPoint coordinate = [[array objectAtIndex:index] CGPointValue];
```

---

You can also define the name for CGPoint like

```
typedef CGPoint YourCustomNameForPoint;
```

then use it like

```
YourCustomNameForPoint coordinate = [[array objectAtIndex:index] CGPointValue];
```

It'll not lead confuse then. ;)

Comment: This is a good option. But I would probably prefer to make a custom class called : PointMutableArray that would be a wrapper around a C array allocated on the heap that would contain the points directly. That would avoid the NSValue call.